# not able to assign an array to another array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have defined kitems as private kitems:any[]; in the class. However not able to assign any value to it using this.kitems = items; I am getting an empty array when I do console.log(this.kitems).

```
createprofile() {
    this._UserRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        let items = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            let item = childSnapshot.val();
            item['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
            items.push(item);
        });
        console.log(items[0].key);
        this.kitems = items;
    }.bind(this));
    console.log(this.kitems);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's because the **on** function is asynchronous and the console log you are watching is done before it gets to run. :)

Comment: try debugging it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a listener to the Firebase Database (with `on()` in your case), it *starts* loading the data from the database. Since this may take some time, the JavaScript code continues executing and your code prints the empty array. Then when the data becomes available from the server, your callback is invoked and adds the data to the array.

This is often easiest to follow if you add some log statements:

```
createprofile() {
    console.log("Start listening");
    this._UserRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log("Got value");
        let items = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            let item = childSnapshot.val();
            item['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
            items.push(item);
        });
        this.kitems = items;
    }.bind(this));
    console.log("After listener");
}
```

The output will be:

> Start listening
>
> After listener
>
> Got value

This is probably not what you expected. But it is inherent to the nature of modern internet based programming. You'll encounter such behavior for most APIs.

A common trick is to frame your code differently when dealing with such a so-called asynchronous API. With traditional programming you often code "first get A, then do B". With an asynchronous API, frame it as "when we get A, we do B with it". In your code that means that you move the code that requires the kitems *into* the callback function:

```
createprofile() {
    this._UserRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        let items = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            let item = childSnapshot.val();
            item['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
            items.push(item);
        });
        this.kitems = items;
        console.log(this.kitems);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Not the kitems will only be logged once the data has come back from the server. Better yet: the Firebase Database synchronizes the data, so your callback will be run *every time the data changes too*.

Since putting the code that needs the kitems into the callback may hurt re-usability, it is common to pass a callback function into the data loading code.

```
createProfileAndThen(callback) {
    this._UserRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        let items = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            let item = childSnapshot.val();
            item['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
            items.push(item);
        });
        this.kitems = items;
        callback(this.kitems);
    }.bind(this));
}

createProfileAndThen(function(kitems) {
    console.log(kitems);
});
```

That's very similar to the callback you pass into Firebase's `on()` function, but then tailored for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `this`. You most likely have the wrong `this`. Use an arrow function:

```
createprofile = () => {
    this._UserRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        let items = [];
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            let item = childSnapshot.val();
            item['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
            items.push(item);
        });
    console.log(items[0].key);
    this.kitems = items;
    });
console.log(this.kitems);
}
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

And try not to use `bind` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html

Comment: Hi @basarat I am getting the this.kitems item if I use console.log inside the snapshot function, just after the statement this.kitems = items. However outside that function if I do console.log(this.kitems) I am getting an empty array.